# How do I disable all code analysis in eclipse cdt?

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, analysis

I am using Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers, Oxygen release (4.7.0).
I have unchecked all boxes in Preferences->Code Analysis.
if I have the following code:

```
int main (void)
{
```

Eclipse places a warning symbol in the border next to the bracket, indicating that it is missing a closing bracket.

How do I disable all code analysis?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You better to as Eclipse suggests and add a closing bracket.

Comment: @VTT why do I need a closing bracket?

Comment: Because of C++ syntax? Also you need to adjust `main` signature because `void` there is not standard.

Comment: Thanks for your shrewd and extremely helpful comments.

Comment: @VTT A lot of times those suggestions are distractions, I do sometimes turn off code analysis. Eclipse simply chocks with huge projects with multiple huge dependent libraries as includes. Try setting up boost indexer for instance, i'm not saying it is not possible, just annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is *Preferences* -> *C/C++* -> *Editor* -> turn off *Report problems as you type*:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In ***Window > Preferences: C/C++ > Editor*** uncheck ***Report problems as you type***.